# How can I get 2-way binding working with ng-repeat and foreach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been progressing fairly well with angularjs with routes, views & ui-bootstrap, but now that I'm working with scope data and two-way binding, I'm having some trouble. With ng-repeat, I found you can also bind the loop to a foreach in your controller to do additional processing, so am trying to get the two working together.

I've been trying to figure out scope in angularjs ng-repeat. I have a list of persons each with a weekSchedule object where I build a table representing a week of schedule info.

I loop the list of persons (outer), then I loop an array numbered 1 - 7 (inner). The schedule data includes a 'day of week' number to match up against the day number and then there's some logic to populate info with schedule times, or leave it blank if no match. but the particulars of that logic aren't important here. For this to work, I need the weekSchedule data for each particular person to be in scope while iterating the inner loop. so I've worked out a more basic example to look at.

I've read quite a few things about this, but can't find a solution. I've tried a million approaches but nothing works. I've tried rootScope, $parent, broadcast, setters & getters, setting the person, then calling the inner loop code via a function, etc, etc.

With my table, I've tried setting the weekScedule in scope via ng-init & ng-model. And also with a 'child scope ng-init with 'day.weekSchedule=person.weekSchedule'. With this it sort of gets the object into scope in the View template, but only the last object. So the object in the 1st outer iteration has the wrong object.

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="person in scheduleData">
        <th ng-init="setWeekSchedule(person.weekSchedule)">{{person.name}}</th>
        <!-- th>{{person.name}}</th -->
        <!-- td width="12%" ng-repeat="day in dayNumbers" ng-model="person.weekSchedule" -->
        <td width="12%" ng-repeat="day in dayNumbers">
            <span ng-init="day.weekSchedule=person.weekSchedule"></span>
            day.id: {{day.id}}<br />
            1st schedule id: {{day.weekSchedule[0].id}}
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>


$scope.dayNumbers = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5},{id:6},{id:7}];

$rootScope.person = {
    weekSchedule: [{ id: 0 }]
};

$rootScope.setWeekSchedule = function(weekSchedule) {    
    $rootScope.person.weekSchedule = weekSchedule;
};

$scope.dayNumbers.forEach(function(day){
    day.weekSchedule = $rootScope.person.weekSchedule;
    console.log('day.id: ' + day.id);
    console.log('1st schedule id: ' + day.weekSchedule[0].id);
});

$scope.scheduleData = [
    {"id":"1","name":"Jim","weekSchedule":[
    {"id":"1001","dow":"1","scheduleDate":"01/08/2016"},
    {"id":"1002","dow":"2","scheduleDate":"01/09/2016"},
    {"id":"1003","dow":"4","scheduleDate":"01/11/2016"},
    {"id":"1004","dow":"5","scheduleDate":"01/12/2016"}]},
    {"id":"1","name":"Kim","weekSchedule":[
    {"id":"1005","dow":"2","scheduleDate":"01/09/2016"},
    {"id":"1006","dow":"3","scheduleDate":"01/10/2016"},
    {"id":"1007","dow":"5","scheduleDate":"01/12/2016"},
    {"id":"1008","dow":"6","scheduleDate":"01/13/2016"}]}
];
```

[image]

No matter how I set the schedule in the controller, I can't access it correctly in the View iterations. No matter how I set the schedule in the View, I can't access (and process) it correctly in the Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that builds a cross reference.

```
$scope.xref = function(schedule) {
    var xref = {};
    angular.forEach(schedule, function(entry) {
        xref[entry.dow] = entry;
    });
    return xref;
};
```

Use that function in your template.

```
<td width="12%" ng-repeat="day in dayNumbers">
    day.id: {{day.id}}<br />
    1st schedule id: {{xref(person.weekSchedule)[day.id].id}}
</td>
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfuxtfjr/).

Comment: Brilliant, works good, thx. After getting nowhere, I took a simpler approach, dropping the 'dayNumbers.forEach' which shadowed the ng-repeat & just passed the 'day.id' and 'schedules' into a function, looped the schedules to find a match and set the schedule as a 'day' property where I can then access them in the View. So now I'm wondering which is more efficient since the xref loops each schedule for each property where my new approach loops once. I'd need a hybrid where I could set the obj from xref as a day property so would only call once per day iteration. So am thinking about that now.

Comment: This example is not efficient because it builds the xref on each iteration. Ideally, one should build the xref once when the data is fetched and update as needed. But it is a good example of how to quickly build an xref. And it quickly solved the problem

Comment: Yes I figured out how to just call it once. The big problem was where I had a foreach bound to and running parallel or shadowing the inner ng-repeat; something I saw in an example somewhere and thought I could use. After dropping that, things got better. A 'schedule' obj has more properties than just a dow or date, but I reduced it to a more basic example here. Now my 'td' uses ng-init to set the xref obj as 'schedule', where in the 'td' I can output any property I want: <td ng-repeat="day in dayNumbers" ng-init="schedule=xref(person.weekSchedule)[day.id]"> Thx George.